# Comparing objects of different classes derived from the same base

Tags: java, inheritance, comparison

I have two classes, let's say DerivedOne and DerivedTwo, derived from a base class Base.

Assuming I have these:

```
DerivedOne d1;
DerivedTwo d2;
```

when I compare d1 and d2, I'd like d1 to always be smaller, in other words an object of DerivedOne should have a higher priority than an object of DerivedTwo. What is the best/nicest way to do that?

Comment: Post your real problem situation. This doesn't seem real, or is not making much sense. Those are not objects, that you have posted, rather `references`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the super class declare a variable as priority.

And in the subclasses constructor, initialize that.

```
class A
{
int priority;
}

class Derived1
{
 Derived1()
 {
  priority=1;
 }
}


class Derived2
{
Derived2()
{
priority=0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I do not know if this is the nicest, but I would recommend using the `instanceof` operator inside the comparator.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably a proper implementation of [`java.util.Comparator<YourSuperClass>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Answer (score 2):

Make both objects implements [`Comparable<Derivedparent>` `interface`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) (or parent implements and subclass override) and then in the CompareTo method put something like this:

```
public class DerivedOne{

public int compareTo(DerivedParent dp){
 if (dp.instanceOf(DerivedTwo){
  return -1;
 }
 //More comparisons
}
}


public class DerivedTwo{

public int compareTo(DerivedParent dp){
 if (dp.instanceOf(DerivedOne){
  return 1;
 }
 //More comparisons
}
}
```